# Variable scope in c# switch

Tags: c#, scope, switch-statement

I'm trying to send an email where the sender and recipient email addresses (and subject and body content) change depending on a value supplied to the method.  It's probably best explained with the code itself:

```
public void EmailNotification(int emailAction)
    {

        MailAddress to;
        MailAddress from;
        string subject;
        string body;

        switch (emailAction)
        {
            case 1:
                // Comment approved
                to = new MailAddress("someone@theirdomain.com");
                from = new MailAddress("no-reply@thisdomain.com");
                subject = "Comment approved";
                body = @"The comment you posted has been approved";
                break;
            case 2:
                // Comment rejected
                to = new MailAddress("someone@theirdomain.com");
                from = new MailAddress("no-reply@thisdomain.com");
                subject = "Comment rejected";
                body = @"The comment you posted has been rejected";
                break;
        }

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in EmailNotification: {0}", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

So the problem is that because of how scope works with switches, the values of to, from, subject etc aren't recognised outside of the switch, even though I've declared them outside of the switch (probably incorrectly?).

I'm a .NET novice, so any advice here on how this kind of thing should be done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just declare the `MailMessage` object before the switch and then use `message.To = new MailAddress("....");` inside the switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not initializing the variables.  What would the values of your variables be if the value of `emailAction` is neither `0` or `1`?  They would be uninitialized, which is illegal.  So either initialize them, or add a `default:` clause to your switch statement that throws an exception.  Either:

```
MailAddress to = null;
MailAddress from = null;
string subject = null;
string body = null;
```

Or:

```
switch (emailAction)
{
    ...
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Action not recognized: " + emailAction);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the variables to a default value, or initialize them in a `default` case. The switch cases are not guaranteed to execute, so the compiler doesn't know that the values will be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a problem with scope, but a problem with ensuring values are initialised.

Swapping "Case 2:" for "Default:" will allow the code to compile, as will setting empty values to your variables (setting MailAddresses to null, and strings to null or "") but I wouldn't recommend that.

In short the reason it fails is that if emailAction were to equal, 3, or anything other than 1, or 2, there would be no action performed in the switch statement and then you would be trying to use uninitialised variables in an expression.

For more information on what initialising is (sorry if this is too low level for you), try reading: http://www.inf.unibz.it/~calvanese/teaching/06-07-ip/lecture-notes/uni02/node18.html .